# How to get type parameter in Java

Tags: java

I have an entity as following :

```
public class Test extends AbstractEntity<Long> implements IHasDate { ... }
```

And it's DAO as following :

```
public class TestDAO extends AbstractDAO<Test, Long> { ... }
```

In the `AbstractDAO` I want to test if the passed type parameter Test is an instance of IHasDate.

This is the defintion of the `AbstractDAO` :

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T extends AbstractEntity<ID>, ID extends Serializable> { 
    public void test(){ 
        // Here I want to test if the passed type parameter is an instance of IHasDate.
    }
}
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: "*`Here I want to test if the passed type parameter is an instance of IHasDate.`*" Which one? `AbstractEntity<ID>` or `ID`? --- You can enforce it through the bound of the generic parameter by e.g. `T extends AbstractEntity<ID> & IHasDate`

Comment: Not a dupe - at best an XY problem.

Comment: @Turing85 the class `Test` is the one that implements `IHasDate`, so in this case `T extends AbstractEntity<ID>` is the one I want to test.

Comment: For reference: [What is the XY-Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki As I said: there is no need to test it, you can enforce it. Maybe you want to talk a little bit more about what problem you are actually trying so solve.

Comment: @Turing85 I dont want to inforce it since there are some other classes that extends `AbstractEntity` but they are not implementing `IHasDate`.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki Again: what is your actual problem? This all sounds very much like an XY-problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

This is fundamentally unnecessary if all you want to do is ensure that your generic is bound properly.

Instead of checking the type inside of your `AbstractDAO`, you require a bound on your `AbstractDAO` to `IHasDate`, although this is clunky.  This means that any entity that *doesn't* extend `IHasDate` that attempts to use this will fail to compile.

```
abstract class AbstractDAO<T extends AbstractEntity<ID> & IHasDate, ID extends Serializable> {
    public void test(){

    }
}
```

Using the above you can accomplish a similar objective if you create a different DAO which binds to `IHasDate`.

```
abstract class IHasDateDao<T extends AbstractEntity<ID> & IHasDate, ID extends Serializable> extends AbstractDAO<T, ID> {
}
```

Comment: "*This is fundamentally unnecessary if all you want to do is ensure that your generic is bound properly.*" - But sadly, this is not what OP wants.

Comment: @Turing85:  They don't want to enforce it on `AbstractDAO`, to which I provide an alternative.

Comment: Life would be sooooo much easier without XY-Problems :)

Answer (score -3):

You can use method instanceof
if(yourObject instanceof yourClass){
...
}

Comment: The method has no parameter, thus you do not necessarily have an instance of your class to work with.